# proper event in google places autocomplete select with mouse

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms, google-places-api

I am using google's autocomplete api just like in the docs and it works 
fine.
However I have a form submitted with ajax every time it changes .
It works fine but when I use the autocomplete for the location with the 
mouse (choosing a place with a click).
It trigger the onchange and submits the form before The location is set.

How can I block this behaviour ?
I mean submit **after** the mouse click on the autocomplete.

Here is a fiddle with an example : http://jsfiddle.net/8GnZB/2/

```
     $(document).ready(function () {
         $location_input = $("#location");
         var options = {
             types: ['(cities)'],
             componentRestrictions: {
                 country: 'be'
             }
         };
         autocomplete = new 
google.maps.places.Autocomplete($location_input.get(0), options);
         $("#search_form input").change(function () {
             var data =  $("#search_form").serialize();
             /* Serialize form & send it to the search view */
             show_submit_data(data);
             return false;
         });
     });

     function show_submit_data(data) {
         $("#result").html(data);
     }

     <script type="text/javascript" 
src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places&sensor=true"></script>
     <form id="search_form" action="" method="post" >location :
         <input id="location" name="location" type="text" />
         <br/>data:
         <input id="data" name="data" type="text" />
     </form>Sent data :
     <div id="result"></div>
```

The only work around I managed to work so far is a timeout on the `change()` event but is kinda ugly.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

To solve your problem you need to bind the correct event for your input, remember that library have their own events.

The object that you're using it's autocomplete

```
autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete($location_input.get(0), options);
```

Now you can bind the event `place_changed` which it's trigger when you needed, in this point you can control whatever you need.

```
google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function() {
    var data = $("#search_form").serialize();
    console.log('blah')
    show_submit_data(data);
});
```

Here's a live example
http://jsfiddle.net/8GnZB/7/

Comment: excellent , I tried this too but somehow I did it wrong , many thanks ;)

Comment: autocomplete.getPlace() will also give you all the information you need about the location selected by the user in your callback function

Comment: Here another function can be used to get the selected data `autocomplete.getPlace()`

Answer (score 2):

You can use below code to listen click event

```
    let input = document.getElementById('searchTextField'); // the input field id from html file
    let autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input);
    google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', () => {
        let place = autocomplete.getPlace();
        console.log(place); // You will get complete data
        // If you want to move your map center to the searched lat long position. Use below any one
        // (with animation)
        this.gmap.panTo({ lat: place.geometry.location.lat(), lng: place.geometry.location.lng() }); 
        // (without animation)
        this.gmap.setCenter({ lat: place.geometry.location.lat(), lng: place.geometry.location.lng() }); 
    });
```

Answer (score -1):

To solve this problem ,you have to add listener which enables you to select places on mouse click.

**Perfectly work on angular2+**

Here is the code

```
   let input1=document.getElementsByTagName('input')[0];
   let autocomplete1 = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input1, {
    types: ["address"]
  });


  this.ngZone.run(() => { 
    autocomplete1.addListener('place_changed', function() {
      let place1=autocomplete1.getPlace();
        this.pickup=place1.formatted_address;              
        console.log(this.pickup);
  })
          })
```

Make sure to run the whole code in ngOnInit() 
and also import ngZone class and declare it in constructor
otherwise ngZone shows error.