# Onchange not detecting field change with Google form autocomplete

Tags: javascript, input, onchange

I have google autocomplete form on my page. What I'm trying to do is to use on change on city field from the form to query base and display result on the page via ajax and php. If you are familiar with googles form autocomplete, user inputs something in one input field and when he has finished form is filled with data.

Problem is that nothing is firing when form is filled with googles function, but when I input manually something in city field everything is working like it should. I've tried with onchange and oninput event but no joy.

Here is html layout:

```
<div id="locationField">
      <input id="place" placeholder="Enter your address"
             onFocus="geolocate()" type="text"></input>
    </div>

    <table id="address">
            <tr>
        <td class="label">City</td>
        <td class="wideField" colspan="3"><input class="field" id="locality"
              disabled="true" **onchange="getCity(this.value)"**></input></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
```

Any other way to detect the change?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [proper event in google places autocomplete select with mouse](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17153847/proper-event-in-google-places-autocomplete-select-with-mouse)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most autocompletes will not trigger an `onchange` event (true of browser autocompletes too).

You'll need to bind the event you want to the Google Maps autocomplete object using `.addListener()`.

For an example check out [this other Stack Overlow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17153847/proper-event-in-google-places-autocomplete-select-with-mouse) (by Jorge) and the fiddle posted in the accepted answer there.

Also see [Google's own documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/events) on how to handle events.